# OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect when using np.vstack()

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, mandelbrot

I'm trying to code up the Mandelbrot set with CPU multiprocessing for more speed. Right now, I want to render a 32768x32768 image of the set. I have been running into an `OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect` when using np.vstack() to convert my file to the correct dimensions near the end.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocessing as mp
import warnings
import time

start = time.time() #to time program

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") #For the overflow and invalid exponent runtime warnings

b = 8192*4 #Length and Width of the 22500

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_cores = mp.cpu_count() 
    Y, X = np.mgrid[-1 * (b // 2):b // 2, -1 * (b // 2):b // 2]  #inclue all four quadrants about (0,0), not just Quadrant I
    
    chunk_size = b // num_cores  
    chunks = []
    
    for i in range(num_cores):   #create the chunks
        start_row = i * chunk_size
        end_row = (i + 1) * chunk_size if i < num_cores - 1 else b
        chunks.append((Y, X, start_row, end_row))

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_cores)
    results = pool.imap(calculate_mandelbrot_chunk, chunks, 3) #this is the memory error for b > 2^14
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
####vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv##################
    a = np.vstack(results)
```

I'm completely dumbfounded as to why this problem is occurring. Everything works fine at 16384x16384 or below, but it seems to crash at 32k or higher. I can't debug this myself either, because it works fine for smaller values of `b`.

Update: since the problem is my PC not being beefy enough, i'm going to take a different approach. Here's the code @jsbueno requested:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_interactions import ioff, panhandler, zoom_factory
import warnings
import time

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")  # For the overflow and invalid exponent runtime warnings

start = time.time()  # to time program

b = 512  # Length and Width of the image
xlims = (-512,512)
ylims = (-512,512)
#(-512, 512)


#scroll code
def on_ylims_change(event_ax):
    global ylims
    ylims = event_ax.get_ylim()

def on_xlims_change(event_ax):
    global xlims
    xlims = event_ax.get_xlim()
    print("Updated xlims:", xlims)
    #blank(xlims, ylims)
    update_plot(xlims, ylims)


#calc mandy's set
def calculate_mandelbrot(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, size=512):
    Y, X = np.mgrid[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
    c = (X + Y * 1j) * (4 / size)  # Complex numbers array
    c = c.astype(np.complex64)  # Save memory
    a = np.copy(c) * 0
    for k in range(64):
        a = a ** 2 + c
    a[a < 100] = 1  # Filter divergents out
    return np.real(a)  # Type casting

def update_plot(xlims, ylims):
    a_zoomed = calculate_mandelbrot(xlims[0], xlims[1], ylims[0], ylims[1], size=b)
    ax.imshow(a_zoomed, cmap="gray", extent=(xlims[0], xlims[1], ylims[0], ylims[1]))

def blank(xlims, ylims):
    a_zoomed = np.zeros([32, 32])
    ax.imshow(a_zoomed, cmap="gray", extent=(xlims[0], xlims[1], ylims[0], ylims[1]))

a = calculate_mandelbrot(xlims[0], xlims[1], ylims[0], ylims[1], size=b)

end = time.time()
print(end - start)

#### scroll wheel zoom ####
with plt.ioff():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(a, cmap="gray", extent=(-512,512,-512,512))
disconnect_zoom = zoom_factory(ax)
ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', on_ylims_change)
ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', on_xlims_change)

pan_handler = panhandler(fig)

plt.show()
```

Note: Each redraw at this b-value takes only `0.3055903911590576 seconds` on my pc. I have an intel i9, so it may be a bit different for others.

[image: Mandebrot Set when panning or zooming]

Edit2: Adding `ax.cla()` above update fixed the issue!

Comment: "Right now, I want to render a 32768x32768 image of the set." How much memory do you expect this to use? Do you have this much available? Have you tried checking the memory usage of your process?

Comment: Since the code is using multiprocessing, please check whether existing Stack Overflow questions - such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379953 - solve the problem for you. (I don't know enough about multiprocessing to verify this for you.) Otherwise, we will need a proper [mre] to diagnose the problem.

Comment: is there more to the error message?  full traceback?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I’ve checked my processing, and for a 32gb array, i have juuuust enough ram to process the matrix multiplication, but not to v stack.  I’m trying to make it more efficient right now, since I’ve notices that the pool returns more arrays that I put in. Hopefully this’ll reduce memory.

Comment: @hpaulj Idon’t have access to my pc right now, but i’ll send it to you when i do!But, I do know that the traceback occurred at np.v stack().

Comment: @KarlKnechtelai checked your question and it didn’t help. I’ll send my full code when I return home. It isn’t that much.

Comment: `vstack` will iterate over results, so if MP has problems accessing a component the error will occur there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply running out of memory.
There is nothing strange about it.

Since you already broken the problem to process things in chunks, that is fixable by changing your process to use smaller chunks, limited to your memory size, instead of cpu count, and write the results to disk - and then use some other utility which can convert your data to a usable image (or use your generated tiles in a pamable and zoomable super-image).

See - at 32K x 32K you have exactly 1024 Megapixels - if each pixel would take 1 byte, that is 1GB. but you are using  64bit ints, so, it is 8GB of memory for your grid on the main process side, and as your code do not worry about any memory saving, at a first look, it might use up to 4 times that. (the grid in the main process as input , then the chunks in the main process, each chunk in the worker process, and the returned chunk, when the subprocess is done)

Anyway, a 32Kx32K image is very little practical - any system you are using to display that will likely have a form of creating a windowed-composite view from the image saved as separate files, in tiles. You should check that option.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll look into the windowed-composite view. Besides changing the int64 to a different type, do you have any other ways to prevent using this much memory?

Comment: other ways is to rewrite the code to generate smaller chnks than 1/CPU count, and write the chunks to disk as tile-images as they get ready. Even if just use some other app to stitch the tiles into a single file.

Comment: Thanks!
For now, I've decided to go in a different direction. Instead of a giant HD file, I'm trying to make my code redraw everything when you zoom in. I hope you don't mind! Your advice was excellent.

Comment: that is actually a better idea. As I don't know how you are using it, I had not suggested that - but I would, if I knew it was interactive

Comment: "*I'm trying to make my code redraw everything when you zoom in.*" Note that if you zoom × 2 you already have a ¼ of the data from the previous.

Comment: Was @AarushAbrol attempting to file the Mandelbrot Set for later retrieval? Given that it's a fractal, that would be a "hiding to nowhere".

Comment: @jsbueno 
I've had some success with making the zoom-in feature. So far, I've incorporated scroll zoom so it zooms as a square, but I need to clean my axes every time I zoom in, and I need to redraw the image too; right now my code zooms until one pixel is the size of the entire canvas and there isn't point in zooming in anymore. I've included the code in my post.

Comment: @WeatherVane The way I want to zoom in to work is that it takes in updated x & y-lims from matplotlib, and re-calculates that portion of the Mandelbrot Set. If I zoom out, the extent would change from the zoomed portion to (-2,2 -2,2) so everything should be alright.